# Canyon ULT and Wahoo Kickr

Tags: frames, carbon, damage, trainer

Bought a wahoo Kickr in November and noticed a small chip to my canyon ultimate carbon frame. In January, Canyon announced the Ultimate was not compatible with Kickr. I'm dealing with Canyon and Wahoo, but curious if I should be concerned by the frame damage. Is this something serious? Bike is a 2021.

[image]

[image: Rubbing on frame just above the dropout on non drive side]

Comment: Maybe bring it up with canyon, something along the lines of “you didn’t tell me it was incompatible when I bought it.”

Comment: https://www.canyon.com/en-gb/support-articles/how-to-use-canyon-bikes-in-turbo-trainer.html it’s a bit of a grey area and always has been for most carbon frames. They say thru axles are fine but further on say the ultimate is not compatible with Wahoo, but I read that as you can use a different trainer. But looking at your frame is it thru axle ?

Comment: This is a QR axle.

Comment: That looks like something was grinding away at the frame.  When the bike is on the trainer, is there any part that would rub that spot on the frame?

Answer (score 2):

Timothy, I am not a frame specialist but I am an aerospace engineer with some knowledge of Carbon Fibre (CF). My advice would be to wait for the Canyon response, they may tell you that you have caused the damage through negligence but **they should also be able to tell you the significance of the damage**. Canyon are a premium supplier so I would expect them to make high quality light weight frames using the minimum amount of material through good design. During development, designers look to provide strength only where it is needed. Poorer quality producers will compensate for poor design by using extra CF and hence more weight. The drop out area is a high load area but some of the material may be to create an aerofoil form - you may be lucky. The damage should be repaired in any case, it will only get worse if left.  My concern in your case is that Canyon know that interference may occur (see Dan K link) but they have not changed the design, indicating it may be a very necessary part of the load path. Have a look here to see how a frame is made. It shows how the strength is only in tension and how the lay up process gives you strength in all directions.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed insight. Canyon assured me it was just paint. I applied a 2 part epoxy to seal the chipped paint.

Comment: That's good news, and the epoxy will fill and prevent decay.